# Lazy Loading not working between multiple Apps in Angular

Tags: angular

I'm trying to set routes between two apps in angular using lazy loading (added code below), it's not working, it's showing a blank screen only.

I want to run the apps by this URL:

Main App:
http://localhost:4200/

Second App
http://localhost:4200/app1

Here is my folder structure,

```
e2e
node_modules
projects
  - app1
     - e2e
     - src
        - app 
        - assets
        - environments
src
  - app 
  - assets
  - environments
```

Here is my Main AppModule:

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    RouterModule,
    AppSharedModule.forRoot(),
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Here is my Main AppRouting Module:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
  {
    path:'app1',
    loadChildren: () => import('../../projects/app1/src/app/app.module')
    .then(m => m.AppSharedModule),
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
    AppSharedModule.forRoot(),
],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Here is My Second App's AppModule:

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }


@NgModule({})
export class AppSharedModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders<AppSharedModule> {
    return {
      ngModule: AppSharedModule
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: What is problem, do you have exception?

Comment: first as i see here, you need a router module for a child. Because you used root module in child and main modules. it is mistake
[docs](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules)

Comment: Actually, i followed this tutorial: https://medium.com/disney-streaming/combining-multiple-angular-applications-into-a-single-one-e87d530d6527

Comment: What i need is, i want to use the apps by url like this: Main App: http://localhost:4200/ Second App http://localhost:4200/app1

Comment: Man, because it is not lazing loading, it is "Combining Multiple Angular Applications into a Single One" it is differente things. What do you need?

Comment: brother, I'm trying to use lazy loading between two apps...

Comment: Could you add jsfiddle?
and what about *.html files. did you add the router-outlet?